# Python: Extracting Set of Values from JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a set of data I am pulling from an API for stock market history. The history is then stored in a file "history.json". I need to get all recurring sets of the key "4. close". There are between 100 days & 10 years of data in a call. The data is formatted like so:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "SPY",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-01-10",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2017-08-18": {
            "1. open": "242.9000",
            "2. high": "244.1900",
            "3. low": "242.2000",
            "4. close": "242.7100",
            "5. volume": "136748000"
        },
        "2017-08-21": {
            "1. open": "242.6400",
            "2. high": "243.2000",
            "3. low": "241.8300",
            "4. close": "242.9000",
            "5. volume": "65469700"
        }
```

Preferably I would like the output in order as a list with the values excluding the keys as a list. It can be called into memory or converted into another file to open - it does need to retain order as it will be used sequentially in the algorithm. (I try to figure things out on my own, I am new to programming though so if you could simplify things as much as possible I would appreciate it.)

Comment: @ScottHunter I looked through several threads that were similar or related. I honestly was just not getting/understanding the correlation in my head between others questions and my own. I apologize if this is an issue, I am working on an open source project and figured this would be a chance to get familiar with using stackoverflow. When I say new this is literally my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can consider this data as nested dictionaries and use it:

```
outlist = [v["4. close"]   for v in mydict["Time Series (Daily)"].values()]
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
['242.7100', '242.9000']
```

Data:

```
mydict = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "SPY",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-01-10",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2017-08-18": {
            "1. open": "242.9000",
            "2. high": "244.1900",
            "3. low": "242.2000",
            "4. close": "242.7100",
            "5. volume": "136748000"
        },
        "2017-08-21": {
            "1. open": "242.6400",
            "2. high": "243.2000",
            "3. low": "241.8300",
            "4. close": "242.9000",
            "5. volume": "65469700"
        }}}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this for me. This information was very helpful in understanding better what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Michael

You can ckeck this url https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

With the function "loads" you can parse your json and you get a list as return

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this! I appreciate your help.